# Passing output stored in single variable into another script using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I am running set of processes each with different outputs in a python script.

Is there a way to set a variable as global so that just the output of that single step can be accessed from other scripts?

Answer (score 6):

[Script tools](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_tools_with_Python/00150000002q000000/), like other [geoprocessing tools](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002s00000002000000), are meant to be able to be chained together in [ModelBuilder](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000001000000), the [Python window](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000017000000) or other scripts/script tools. You can set up output [parameters](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000n000000) that you can access as output nodes in ModelBuilder, or as result values within the [`Result`](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000) object in a script.

[image: Output Parameters in ModelBuilder]

Output parameters can be set directly as part of the user-exposed parameters, derived from an input parameter, or derived within the script. If it is derived within the script, you can use [`SetParameterAsText()`](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000067000000) to set the output value within the script.

If you have a homogenous set of data elements (tables, feature classes, etc.) being output by your script, you could use a [multi-value](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000013000000) output parameter and set it by joining the items with semicolons, e.g. `arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, ';'.join(outputvalues))`.

You could then split those semicolon-delimited values into a list and iterate over it in a subsequent script tool using, e.g. `inputvalues = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(';')`, use an [Iterate Multivalue](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000000w000000) iterator in ModelBuilder, or simply pass the multivalue parameter directly to a tool or function that supports them.

Hope that gives you some idea of the possibilities!

Comment: 'Obtained from' option seems what i am looking for to pass variables to and fro between codes. Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. Read more about the "Obtained from" setting here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm

Answer (score 2):

This very much depends on your python programming skills. Pyton has sophisticated ways of handling variables between functions.

The simplest way of handling variables could be to write the variable to a file. The variable is then picked up by the other script.

- [Python reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Since you probably are using arcpy with shapefiles, why not use arcpy to either manipulate the contents of your shapefile dbf, or just a plain dbf-file?

- [Add field data to a shapefile](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000)
- [Create a dbf-file within arcpy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n5000000)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
My work involve converting some of the avenue codes into python. Codes in avenue are talking to each other and passing variable values which is what i want to achieve with python. I think writing all function values to a file and calling them at need will be easy structure approach. I'll give it a try!